# Can a bibliography driver choose where to put a pinpoint reference / postnote?

Tags: biblatex, citing, legal-style

I'm writing a bibliography driver to handle case citations in a particular style (AGLC, not that it matters).

Normal citations follow a standard format:

> {prenote} {name} {note} {postnote}

So, for example, we might have:

> See *Smith v Jones* (2002) 123 CLR 456, 512

where 512 is the pinpoint reference, taken from the postnote.

For some reason, however, when citing US cases, the format has to look something like this:

> See *Smith v Jones*, 12 F 3d 456, 512 (7th Cir, 2002)

where, again, 512 is the pinpoint reference.

---

I can't seem to work out how to write a bibliography driver which will insert the pinpoint reference / the postnote in the middle of the reference.

**Is it possible for a bibliography driver to print some fields, then print the postnote, then print some more fields?**

I'm wondering whether I have to change the cite command as well, or perhaps put some sort of hook into the postnote macro.

---

Relevant existing code:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{jurisdiction}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\thefield{type}}{US}}{% US cases have commas after the title
        \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
    }{% type != US (normal behaviour)
        \setunit{\addspace}%
    }%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {% precode
      \usebibmacro{prenote}%
  }{% loopcode
      \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
      \usebibmacro{cite}%
  }{% sepcode
      \multicitedelim%
  }{% postcode
      \usebibmacro{cite:postnote}%
  }
```

---

I've tried calling `\usebibmacro{cite:postntoe}` from the driver, which works.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to set up a toggle/bool which is shared between the bbx file (which has the driver) and the cbx file (with the cite command) so that the reference isn't repeated in the cite command.

---

EDIT: Sorted it using a `\global` toggle.  I'll add in an answer, and delete this note, later on.

Comment: Since you were able to resolve the problem it would be nice if you could add an answer, so we can finally mark this question as answered.

Comment: Is there any chance you are going to add the answer you mentioned in the edit above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by the OP

Comment: A toggle is useful to switch between two styles within the same cite command. Given a US legal reference of
A v B, 123 US 456 (1947),
then \cite[458]{ab}, following BlueBook style, for example,
produces
A v B, 123 US 456, 458 (1947)
with the postnote inside the cite item,
whereas elsewhere in the Common Law world,
with a reference like
C v D, (1960) 84 CLR 124
\cite[158]{cd}, following, say, the AGLC or OSCOLA legal citation styles,
produces 
C v D, (1960) 84 CLR 124, 158
with the postnote after the reference.
Using options at biblatex, entrytype & entry levels is more practical.

Comment: The OP is in effect asking how to conditionally put the postnote inside the loopcode of a cite command (and implicitly empty the postcode to avoid repeating the postnote). Example, if the loopcode does this: {\iftoggle{mainmcgill}%
 {\footnote{\usebibmacro{prenote}\usebibmacro{getcasenameref-mcgill}\usebibmacro{postnote}}}{...}. The use of a toggle becomes extremely unwieldly very quickly when the number of styles to be handled in this way by the cite command reaches a certain size (n > 4).